# Any short formula for PCB trace capacitance when w/h <<1

Tags: pcb, capacitance, trace, equation

I have this formula/equation e(w/d) for capacitance of PCB traces (parallel plate). But as it appears, this equation is valid for the assumption w/d>>1 (much greater). And multiplying 11.3 with d for getting pF/cm, do not know the derivation, but I want the unit to be pF/cm.

I want to learn if there is any similar shortcut formula/equation for trace capacitance when w/d<<1 (much less).

I would also like to understand how the 11.3 came.

NB: Edited the question. I swapped the greater than and less than signs mistakenly.[image]![enter image description here]

Comment: show references

Comment: I have added a screenshot from RF circuit design by Ludwig. Seems like there is some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you were using is missing. If you would like to know about this 11.3 coefficient, you can probably check at IPC2221A standards and replace fixed-value (like speed of light, dielectric constant for FR4, ...) by their numerical expression to obtain this 11.3 (worth a try).
About this case were w>>h, my advice would be to download a tool like "Saturn PCB Design Toolkit" to get a pretty accurate result for microstrip/stripline (...) capacitance. I did a quick simulation with Hyperlynx, and Saturn PCB's results are fine.

### added by t.s.

[image]

**Clearly, the C value is inverse with h gap when w/h >>1.**

e.g. for w/h=10, Dk=4.6 reduces to Dk'=4.0  C= 45 pF/mm in trace length, L~ 9.9 nH/mm and Zo = 14.8 Ohms.

Like in buried capacitance thin substrate PCB's and capacitor's alike w/h is very large >>1000 then these values approach 4071 pF/mm rather than 4500 pF/mm due to the reduced loss of Dk' approaching Dk.

Thus reducing h 50% will double C, reducing h to 10% will increase C x10.. *almost..* There is a slight reduction in "effective dielectric constant also"  https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/keffective

Thus as L is proportional and C is inversely proportional, the Characteristic Impedance sqrt(L/C) is inverse with h or is proportional to w for a fix h in pF/length.  i.e. a reduction of 2:1 in height results in  \$Z^2= 0.5L/2C = 1/4 * L/C\$ and thus square root reduces Zo 2:1 thus Zo reduces linearly with gap or height in square parallel planes.

from Saturn PCB Toolkit computing C in area/h sensitivity by using the same units for length and width, C 409 pF/sq.mm @ 1.07 Ohms for square:h=100:1  and 4071 pF/sq.mm. @ 0.175 Ohms for square:h=1000:1

Comment: You mean, a short formula like e(w/h) for w>>h, does not exist for w<<h?

Comment: You did not show where this e(w/h) comes from : application note ? I've never used these simplified formulas on my job

Comment: There, i have edited my question and added a screenshot from RF circuit design by Ludwig. There you see, formula for capacitance of parallel plate transmission line.

Comment: Sorry if I took anything wrong. But my question is, is there any short formula for w/h<<1 as there is for w/h>>1, which is, as you see, e(w/h). Or do you mean, there is not, we have to go for simulation? Like, for trace width 0.2 mm and substrate thickness 0.9 mm.

Comment: When using the formula e(w/h) with w/h>>1 you obtain for h = 0.2mm and w = 1mm about 1.63pF/cm (microstrip, e_r = 3.69). When using Saturn PCB Design and their much more complex formula you obtain 2.53pF/cm ... which is 50% more ! Therefore, I would recommand you to always go for Saturn PCB design or simulation (at least for a complex controlled impedance HDI PCB), **whatever the w/h ratio is**

Comment: Ok. So, this means, there is no shortcut formula. The remaining option is, simulation.